# How to create a simple grid-like layout with proper value alignment in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, tableview

I basically need to create the following grid-like layout:

[image]

My current attempt is to make this a UITableView with custom cells: The first one beign the red rounded rectangle as well as the 3 static columns (Name, balance, currency) and every row after that would be represented by another custom cell with every value.

The columns (within the first table view cell) are represented by a Horizontal Stack with equal spacing and the value rows would be represented by another Horizontal Stack with exactly the same constraints and spacing as the column horizontal stack (this is my attempt of ensuring that the values actually align with the column titles).

However, while the layout ends up being similar, the values dont quite exactly match the titles, I need the values to be centered to the titles, which isnt happening. I tried playing with the stacks multiple distribution types, but cant seem to get the desired result.

ViewController code is the typical:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderTableViewCell
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RowTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RowTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            return 100
    default:
        return 50
    }
}
```

}

Current layout is (ended up being similar, just not perfectly aligned nor unsure how would the UI react should I need to use large numbers):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Fod.png

Any input is welcomed.

Comment: For this level of control I always find it far quicker to build my own cell from the different components and specify the design and relationships directly with autolayout constraints.

Comment: Hmm not sure I understood you there honestly. You mean having a single UITableViewCell and doing everything there?

Comment: Single TVC for each row.  Like in the answer by liquid.  This gives you the absolute control of the layout, handling large values, etc etc

Comment: @stompy - *"simple grid-like layout"* is not really **simple**. Will your Names column only contain the name "John"? Will the Balance column never exceed 4 digits? How should it look if the name is "Stanley Livingston" and he has a balance of "$2,345.678"? I **strongly** suggest you take the time to mock-up your layout using varying length names and balances. In the process, you may find that you need to re-think your layout quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd probably do is just construct a cell with 3 labels and constrain them to each other with the use of multipliers so that their widths are determined by the width of the view (ultimately the table) and not its contents. Plug this into a Playground and mess around with it.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    static let reuseId = "cell"
    let nameLabel = UILabel()
    let balanceLabel = UILabel()
    let currencyLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = .darkGray
        addLabels()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
    
    private func addLabels() {
        let firstColumn = UIView()
        firstColumn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(firstColumn)
        firstColumn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        firstColumn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        firstColumn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        firstColumn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4).isActive = true
        
        let secondColumn = UIView()
        secondColumn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(secondColumn)
        secondColumn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstColumn.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        secondColumn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        secondColumn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
        
        let thirdColumn = UIView()
        thirdColumn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(thirdColumn)
        thirdColumn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondColumn.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        thirdColumn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        thirdColumn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
        thirdColumn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        nameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstColumn.addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstColumn.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstColumn.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstColumn.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstColumn.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        
        balanceLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        balanceLabel.textAlignment = .center
        balanceLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        balanceLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        balanceLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondColumn.addSubview(balanceLabel)
        balanceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondColumn.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        balanceLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondColumn.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        balanceLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondColumn.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        balanceLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondColumn.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        
        currencyLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        currencyLabel.textAlignment = .center
        currencyLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        currencyLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        currencyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        thirdColumn.addSubview(currencyLabel)
        currencyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdColumn.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        currencyLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdColumn.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        currencyLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdColumn.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        currencyLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdColumn.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    }
}

class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Cell.reuseId)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    // MARK: TABLE VIEW DATA SOURCE
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.nameLabel.text = "John Smith"
        cell.balanceLabel.text = "$5,890,223,000,000"
        cell.currencyLabel.text = "EUR"
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: TABLE VIEW DELEGATE
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = VC()
```

Comment: Hi ! For whatever reason I never got notified of this reply and literally just see this. My apologies.
So your approach would be to set the widths of the value labels based on a % of the available width, right? As in assigning 20% to name, 20% to balance and 20% to currency for example? And what values would you assign to the header labels (Name, balance and currency) to ensure they always align to its corresponding values? The same 20%? If you could add the code for the constraints of the titles that would be awesome. Thanks and sorry for not seeing this sooner!

Comment: @stompy if you anchor the widths of both the header labels and the value labels to the superview (i.e. `equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3`) then they will always render identically. Just make sure that they add up to 100% so they fill out the view (i.e. 40%, 30%, 30%).

Comment: @stompy I updated my answer with actual cells. Plug that into a Playground.

Comment: Thank you so much @liquid ! I re did my constraints using multipliers and now everything seems to be aligning much better across all devices, even iPod touches and iPads! I was previously using hardcoded frames and while it worked on the majority of devices, iPods and iPads were either lacking space on smaller screens or had way too much space on largers screen.  By the way, to avoid labels from trimming on smaller screens I am currently using `confirmButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5`, would that be good or is there any other way to make my labels/buttons resize on small screens?

Comment: @stompy `minimumScaleFactor` is probably the best way to get those large labels to fit. And you should always rely on constraints (if you're using UIKit) over hard-coding frame sizes where possible.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was using constraints, just hardcoding the width, but thats still using constraints, right? And yeah, I did try doing this in SwiftUI but failed miserably as all the options required using PreferenceKey which I havent really grasped yet.

Comment: @stompy yeah, you're technically using constraints but almost defeating their purpose if you aren't taking advantage of the anchors and multipliers.

Comment: Absolutely. Anyhow, thank you so much once again. Ill mark your answer as the solution now!